# Open edx with keycloak OIDC [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: keycloak, python-social-auth, openedx

I am trying unsuccessfully to use KEYCLOAK to authenticate my edx users without success,

I followed the doc instructions to add a third party auth and everything works fine, but when I try to authenticate a user through the keyclok form I get the following error:

```sh
9112 [social] [user None] [ip 41.221.187.207] middleware.py:40 -
Authentication failed: HTTPSConnectionPool (host = 'mali-id.ml', port
= 443): Max retries exceeded with url: / auth / realms / Mali-Id / protocol / openid-connect / token (Caused by SSLError
(SSLCertVerificationError (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
(_ssl.c: 1125)')))
```

My stack is configured as follows:

- Keycloak deployed on Docker with Nginx as a proxy that listens on ports 80 and 443 on a separate vm
- Edx deployed by Bitnami on a GCP vm